# Why ControlBindingsCollection.Add's datasource is an object and not INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

On [the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158437(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ControlBindingsCollection.Add Method (String, Object, String, Boolean, DataSourceUpdateMode, Object)
```

The second parameter is the `dataSource`, of the type `object`.

From my testing, this `dataSource` has to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`, without which the binding will not work.

My question is, why is it that in that method, it takes in an `Object` for the `dataSource`, instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Is there other ways that one can do the binding without inheriting the `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

I've searched the internet but can't find any relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is just necessary for having two-way data-binding. In cases which you use one-way data-binding, the object doesn't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

- One-way data-binding: Control changes will push to data source.
- Two-Way data-binding: In addition to one-way, data source changes will push to control.

Here is how two-way data-binding works:

The `Binding` object, subscribes for `ValueChanged` event of the `PropertyDescriptor` of the bound property. The `PropertyDescriptor` checks if the container object is `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then will subscribe for its `PropertyChanged` to raise `ValueChanged` event. This way, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` will notify the `Binding` object about the change in data source property value. Then the binding pulls data and will update the bound control property.